# Unit Testing using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I want to create a unit testing framework which has its own front end gui. The testing framework in which I want to create, should be able to insert a visual studio solution along with a pre-created XML file which contains test data and expected results for each unit test. My question is how would I go about finding declarations of test classes in the existing projects in which I would import? The idea behind this is that this can be left running over night if needs be to import a large number of solutions, extract the test classes and run the unit tests on each class. Behind the scenes I would like to use Microsofts Visual Studio own unit testing framework, it is not possible for us to use nunit.

Whats the best way for me to go about this please?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to schedule `Test Runs`. Why do you want to complicate it so much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should just use *entirely* normal unit test infrastructure - and just have a class library which makes it easy to perform the "process input, check output" step.

You shouldn't have to reinvent the wheel of finding test classes etc... nor would I recommend creating your own frontend. By using the stock infrastructure, you're likely to be able to save yourself a bunch of work - and that time can be invested in things like making failure messages really clear in a business-specific way.

Comment: Thanks, although I should have added originally that we require the ability to either run a single test or a whole suite of tests. Out of the box is MS Test able to import test cases from the likes of XML?

Answer (score 0):

I know you said specifically VS2010, but if you want to do this kind of thing, you should at least take the time to look at the new Unit Testing features in Visual Studio 2012. Check out this video from TechEd Europe 2012 for more info and some examples (I'm sure a little searching will provide more usefull info too):

- [Introducing the New Visual Studio 2012 Unit Testing Experience](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/DEV214)

I believe it is possible to write extensions or plugins of some sort for this. If I remember correctly, it also provides a command line interface - maybe you can use this / communicate with it from your own GUI? I'm sure you should be able to find something beneficial to your project in there anyway.

I would in any case steer clear of VS2010 for this unless it was absolutely necessary.